# Calling a method in my HomeController from my Masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, master-pages

Im trying to hide some admin specific buttons on my masterpage from users with no adminrights.

my code looks like this so far:

```
<% if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {%>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Administrer", "Index", "User", new { Area = "Users" }, new { @class = "menubutton", @id = "settingsbutton" })%>
      <%} else { }%>
```

now i want to do a check in the IF() statement if the current user is an administrator. im using the ASP.NET membership system and have a speciel class attached to each user with some exstra information including information about if he is an admin or not (bool).

my question is how do i go about calling a method that checks this or something similar?

Comment: I was thinking it would be something like if (Request.IsAuthenticated && "Method that checks for adminrights")

Comment: i just dont know how to call such a method from the masterpage to a controller

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409213/how-can-i-create-a-view-that-has-different-displays-according-to-the-role-the-us or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610749/asp-net-mvc-check-role-inside-view

Comment: Not exactly the solution i was looking for but it definately has some advantages to it. thank you

Comment: @AronChan What *are* you looking for? The `System.Security.Principal` (User) is available in the View. Is that the object you have attached extra info to?

Comment: I have an object attached to the ASP.NET user which is basicly a collection of items that is attached to that user. my first thought was to use it to determine if the user was admin or not. but i see now that it is much better to use the role system already in place :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<% if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
    {%>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Administrer", "Index", "User", new { Area = "Users" }, new { @class = "menubutton", @id = "settingsbutton" })%>
      <%} else { }%>
```

If you are using the ASP.NET Membership Provider and the ASP.NET Role Provider to link your users to their roles, you can just invoke the `IsInRole(string`) method on your view's `IPrincipal User` object.

Comment: It seems that i dont have the IPrincipal User object. how exactly do i go about getting that?

Comment: I managed to access my user by using:    HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("administrator")

Is this just as good as your example or is there a specific reason that you did it that way?

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("administrator")` is fine. Maybe it's only MVC3 or the Razor view engine that provides @User by default in the view page.